# How to add new keys and values to existing hash table in R?

Tags: r, hash

Using hash package in R I created a hast table with keys and values. I want to add new keys and values to the existing hashtable. Is there any way?

Suppose

```
ht <- hash(keys = letters, values = 1:26)
```

And I need to add new keys and values to ht.
Is there any way other than 
 for eg :

```
ht$zzz <- 45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hash/hash.pdf) for the `hash` package provides a number of syntax varieties for adding new elements to a hash:

```
h <- hash()
.set( h, keys=letters, values=1:26 )
.set( h, a="foo", b="bar", c="baz" )
.set( h, c( aa="foo", ab="bar", ac="baz" ) )
```

The first `.set` option would seem to be the best for bulk inserts of key value pairs.  You would only need a pair of vectors, ordered in such a way that the key value representation is setup the way you want.